# Custom Spinner Drop Down View Listener

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have implemented a custom spinner which extends `BaseAdapter` and I have overridden `getView()` and `getDropDownView()` in that so as to have different views for spinner and drop down item.

How do I get notified when drop down view of spinner is opened or closed?

My Custom spinner class is like this :

```
public class CustomSpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

}

@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add open and close listener on your custom spinner

```
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.util.AttributeSet;
    import android.widget.Spinner;

    public class CustomSpinner extends Spinner {
    // private static final String TAG = "CustomSpinner";
    private OnSpinnerEventsListener mListener;
    private boolean mOpenInitiated = false;

    public CustomSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int mode) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, mode);
    }

    public CustomSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public CustomSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomSpinner(Context context, int mode) {
        super(context, mode);
    }

    public CustomSpinner(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public interface OnSpinnerEventsListener {

        void onSpinnerOpened(Spinner spin);

        void onSpinnerClosed(Spinner spin);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean performClick() {
        // register that the Spinner was opened so we have a status
        // indicator for the activity(which may lose focus for some other
        // reasons)
        mOpenInitiated = true;
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onSpinnerOpened(this);
        }
        return super.performClick();
    }

    public void setSpinnerEventsListener(OnSpinnerEventsListener onSpinnerEventsListener) {
        mListener = onSpinnerEventsListener;
    }

    /**
     * Propagate the closed Spinner event to the listener from outside.
     */
    public void performClosedEvent() {
        mOpenInitiated = false;
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onSpinnerClosed(this);
        }
    }

    /**
     * A boolean flag indicating that the Spinner triggered an open event.
     * 
     * @return true for opened Spinner
     */
    public boolean hasBeenOpened() {
        return mOpenInitiated;
    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasWindowFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasWindowFocus);
        if (hasBeenOpened() && hasWindowFocus) {
            performClosedEvent();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Creating Custom Spinner extending Spinner class does not provide getView() and getDropDownView() methods to override. I have custom layout for drop down view and spinner view.

Answer (score 0):

- For custom view of spinner we have to build custom adapter class.
- All events, listeners etc. default methods of spinner will work same on custom spinner view.

Therefore, you can implement code for open/close of spinner in `ItemSelectedListener` method.

```
mSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            ...
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) { }
    });
```

Comment: can you be more elaborate on how someone knows if spinner is opened if user has not selected any item from dropdown list. OnItemSelectedListener is called only after user selects any item from drop down.